# Selecting from four tables and grouping some results into one column

Tags: mysql, json, group-by, mariadb, group-concat

**sports_games Table**

```
==========================================================================
| game_id | team_id | game_type | time_started | time_ended | planned_by |
|========================================================================|
|   1     |    1    |     1     | 1640799417   | 1641146196 |     1      |
|   2     |    2    |     1     | 1640971535   | 1641579516 |     1      |
|   3     |    1    |     2     | 1640971553   | 1641582723 |     8      |
|   4     |    2    |     2     | 1640971585   | 1641404242 |     9      |
|   5     |    3    |     4     | 1641061431   | 1641754479 |     12     |
==========================================================================
```

I have been able to combine the above table, with the below table;

**game_types Table**

```
==============================
| game_type | game_type_name |
|============================|
|     1     |   football     |
|     2     |   baseball     |
|     3     |     golf       |
|     4     |    tennis      |
==============================
```

With the following SQL

```
SELECT *
    FROM sport_games
    INNER JOIN game_types
    ON sport_games.game_type = game_types.game_type
```

However, I am now finding myself going round and around, attempting potential solution after the other. I need to include data from two more tables, `participents` and `user_basic`.

The `participents` table simply has the `game_id` and `user_id` columns, one row per participant, both combined to be the primary key, and within `user_basic` table, you can find `user_id` along with their `user_name`.

For the `planned_by` column in the firt table, this is also a `user_id` which I want to obtain their username too.

With all the participants, I would like them to be within one column grouped by their game.

**Things That I've Tried**

- `group_concat( .. )`, perhaps I was using this completely wrong, I could only achieve this grouping the entire results set from the other table and could not seem to figure out how to use this in a join correctly.
- `STRING_AGG( ... )` Initially this lead down a path of turning out that I could not use this as I was running on 5.5 MariaDB, which lead down struggling path for me to update. Now I'm using MariaDB 10.3, however I still cannot seem to get the simplest function to work for this, despite going through several Stack Overflows and whatnot.

I feel like I'm at a bit of a loss, any progress I seem to make forward, I am taking two steps back! And then there is using the `JOIN` amongst these, I'm not sure if I am wording my searches right to place me on the right path, so my question title might be a bit ambiguous right now, sorry if this is the case! - Please suggest otherwise, thank you.

**Example Desired Outcome**

```
"2": { // <- game_id
        "game_type": 2,
        "game_type_name": "baseball",
        "participants": {
            "1": "username_1",
            "2": "username_21",
            "3": "username_3",
            "4": "username_4",
        },
        "time_started": 1641061431,
        "time_completed": 1641754479,
        "planned_by": {
            "851730": "username_1",
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see no pdo here
 Neither in the code nor in the problem description

Comment: Post sample data of all 4 tables and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I used the PDO tag as the SQL is done through PDO and I am completely sure whether my SQL is wrong or perhaps PDO classes. Everything has been working so far using them, but now I am entering a more advanced selects and whatnot.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove php and add more sql, like table structures, data examples and desired output.

Comment: @forpas as mentioned, the `participents` and `user_basic` tables are just tables with two columns in. I understand about the expected results though, I will update now!

Comment: I am also programming with disabilities, please bear with me to update my question, sorry for the delay and thank you all for your interest in helping!

Comment: Did you try those selects in the sql console? If not then you should. It's simple as hell to get rid of a question "whether it's x or y". Just remove y

Comment: Do you want the columns participants and planned_by as json?

Comment: It is also possible that your problem can be solved using more than one query. It could be just simpler than one complex query

Comment: Yes, I set the header and output as a json.

eg:
```header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($sports_games, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);```

Comment: Is time_ready a column in the table sports_games?

Comment: @forpas sorry, old line left in by mistake, thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I noticed that you mention that the MariaDB version you are using is 10.3 which does not support Json aggregate functions like JSON_ARRAYAGG() (introduced in version 10.5). Do you want a solution without json results, as comma separated lists with GROUP_CONCAT()?

Comment: @forpas I use Plesk and it shows that it is up to date `mariadb-server-10.3`, however if you recommend, I will look into updating manually, but within Plesk, it will not allow any 'easy' updates.

Comment: I don't know about Plesk. You can check my answer where I posted 2 solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join properly the tables and the table `user_basic` twice: to get the participants and the user who planned the game.

For MariaDB 10.5+ you can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`:

```
SELECT sg.game_id, 
       sg.game_type,
       gt.game_type_name,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(ub.user_id, ub.user_name)) participants,
       sg.time_started,
       sg.time_ended,
       JSON_OBJECT(sg.planned_by, pb.user_name) planned_by
FROM sports_games sg
INNER JOIN user_basic pb ON pb.user_id = sg.planned_by
INNER JOIN game_types gt ON gt.game_type = sg.game_type
INNER JOIN participents p ON p.game_id = sg.game_id
INNER JOIN user_basic ub ON ub.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY sg.game_id;
```

For previous versions use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT sg.game_id, 
       sg.game_type,
       gt.game_type_name,
       CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(ub.user_id, ' : ', ub.user_name SEPARATOR ', '), '}') participants,
       sg.time_started,
       sg.time_ended,
       CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sg.planned_by, ' : ', pb.user_name), '}') planned_by
FROM sports_games sg
INNER JOIN user_basic pb ON pb.user_id = sg.planned_by
INNER JOIN game_types gt ON gt.game_type = sg.game_type
INNER JOIN participents p ON p.game_id = sg.game_id
INNER JOIN user_basic ub ON ub.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY sg.game_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4a558068308b575116e00c3506b5ed95).

Comment: `sg` looks like an alias, however I thought you had to declaire wthese with `AS`? Is this another way to do this `FROM sports_games sg`? You can give it another name here?

Comment: @TimMarshall you can give any alias that you want. The AS keyword can be omitted and I rarely use it.

Comment: This is working perfectly, just one thing I'm not so sure about, the `participants` and `planned_by` when I use your 2nd option for my DB version, they are enclosed with quotation marks, eg; `"planned_by": "{1234 : username}"`, whereas I thought this should be `"planned_by": {1234: "username" }`? Perhaps it is the way I use `json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`.

Comment: Hoping you can help me unerstand the above outcome being in quotation marks as I'm not sure if this is down to me, or your code. I'm very satisfied otherwise and really appreciate your help. Will accept as answer once I hear back. Thanks

Comment: @TimMarshall the result you see is how MariaDB's json aggregate functions return the json objects. I don't know how json_encode() works and if it would be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is `time_ready` an existing column or calculated from other columns? I don't see `time_ready` in any of the provided tables.

```
SELECT 
   game_types.game_type
   , game_types.game_type_name
   , participents.user_id
   , user_basic.user_name
   , sports_games.time_started
   , sports_games.time_ended AS time_completed
   , sports_games.planned_by
FROM sports_games
INNER JOIN game_types
   ON sports_games.game_type = game_types.game_type
INNER JOIN participents
   ON sports_games.game_id = participents.game_id
INNER JOIN user_basic
   ON participants.user_id = user_basic.user_id
ORDER BY
   game_types.game_type
```

Comment: Please bear with me whilst I fully look into what you've suggested. The only initial problem I potentially see is `planned_by`  does not look up `user_basic.user_id` for the `user_name`, perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: @TimMarshall I got ```planned_by``` from the table ```sports_games```, and this is the table flow from ```planned_by``` to ```user_name```: ```sports_games``` --> ```participents``` --> ```user_basic```.  Could you please clarify what you mean when saying that "```planned_by``` does not look up ```user_basic.user_id``` for the ```user_name```"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am not saying it doesn't, trying to understand what you have done. Attempting to put this to practice on my server, noticed some slight wording differences I have to my question.

Where you have `FROM sport_games`  is this ment to say `FROM sports_games`? As the other tables are referenced in the `SELECT` section? Not certain, so just want to clarify please.

Comment: Yes, that should say ```sports_games``` throughout. Thank you for pointing that out, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I have just got your code working on my local and it resulted in:

    {
        "crime_type": "2",
        "game_type_name": "baseball",
        "user_name": "Sarah",
        "time_started": "1643303064",
        "time_ended": "1643478101",
        "planned_by": "130"
    },

The participents are not grouped, I get one of these for each participent and I'm not sure what the planned_by has no user_name attached.

Comment: Let me know if that is too messy above, it doesn't allow multiple line here, I'll edit my question with a not to you.

Comment: How should the participants be grouped? Do you want all participant names that have the same game type to be concatenated together in one row, e.g. "Jane Doe, John Doe"?

Comment: forpas has answered this grouping everything as desired, but I really do appreciate your time spent helping here :)

Comment: Of course, glad that you found your answer. :)